# I can not get my deny from all to work in my Htaccess for everyone

Tags: .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/notfound.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/notfound.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/notfound.html

Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?operationtoad.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(rar|exe|zip|html)$ - [F]
</IfModule>

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from ##.###.###.##
```

When I add a second or third person in on a second allow from line, they can see the main site, but they are unable to go to /notfound.html or /anonexistingfile.html - they will either see the apache starter page or they get a 500 error.

Now if I remove myself from this I just get apache test page on the root and 403 forbidden on the others.

Answer (score 0):

Not really the answer but...
Instead of allowing IP, you can replace this by an htpassword.

And double check your RewriteRule condition, maybe a bug inside it.